# Opesource Software for Note management

Tags: php, mysql

Im about to start building some software to manage my college notes, a simple web GUI , which will allow me to create folders for each subject and upload my course notes to those folders so that i have all my notes stored easily online and i can them access from anywhere, rather than go to each lecturers individual page to download them - or more likely hunting them down just before exams :)

I've a cool domain to host it on, so would open it up for public use, i know a good few people already who would like to avail of this.

My question is, before i start to hand code it, is there anything currently in the market or that can be hacked together to achieve this already?

Comment: There are online file storage services, such as Dropbox. They work quite well and are easy to use...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out http://eyeos.com/

> eyeOS is a disruptive desktop entirely
>   usable from a  web browser. It
>   includes an office suite and some
>   collaboration  aplications, as well as
>   a full framework to develop new web
>   apps as if  they were desktop apps.
>   It's Free and Open Source & so you can
>   host your  own system, keeping all
>   your data under your control.
>
> With just an Internet capable device
>   you can access all your files,  no
>   matter where you are. That is, just
>   open your eyeOS desktop in an 
>   Internet café in Paris. Travel to
>   Sydney and open your eyeOS system from
>   another computer. It is exactly the
>   same desktop, with all your  documents
>   and applications available.